# How to get html from input and save as variable in Python Django

Tags: python, html, django, forms

I'm trying to get a simple input (which would be an integer) from the user, and use it as a variable in the next python function. But whenever I try to print the input it returns `None`.
Here's my code:

HTML

```html
  <form action="/./" method="POST">{% csrf_token %}
        <input type="text" name="quantity" placeholder="Repeat" size=2>
        <input type="submit" value="Save!">
      </form>
```

Python Django (This is just part of the function.)

```py
def saveCriteria(request):
    title = request.POST.get('quantity')
    context = {}
    print(title)
    return render(request, "home.html", context)
```

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It prints an empty list "[]"

Comment: No JS involved. Pure html

Answer (score 2):

You should add `if` statement before that:

```
def saveCriteria(request):
    context = {}
    if request.method == "POST":
        title = request.POST.get('quantity')
        print(title)
    return render(request, "home.html", context)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should refer to the view function in the html template:

```
 <form action="url of saveCriteria" method="POST"> 
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="text" name="quantity" placeholder="Repeat" size=2>
        <input type="submit" value="Save!">
 </form>
```